# Protecting astronauts from G's when taking off/landing

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, angular-velocity

When landing from orbit or launching from the ground to orbit (with chemical rockets or other means of fast acceleration), could one place the astronauts in a centrifuge and spin it to protect them from greater G's than the 10 they are limited to and allow faster takeoffs/landings?

Answer (score 3):

If you place the astronauts in a centrifuge, then at some point you're actually increasing the G's that they experience.

Think about it. If the centrifuge spins about a horizontal axis, then when the astronaut reaches the bottom of that spin, they'll feel extra force downward, even though they might be weightless at the top of the spin.

If the centrifuge spins about a vertical axis, you're doing nothing to help the astronaut because the centrifugal force they feel (which is fictitious) will be directed horizontally outward. Then they'll feel that horizontal force in addition to the gravitational force.

Answer (score 1):

As MSha has explained, centrifuges won't work. The only way to protect astronauts from g-forces is to transfer the normal force that act on their bodies in a different way. The problem is that normal forces only act on the boundary surface. Obviously the entire volume of the astronauts will be accelerated, this means that that the force acting on each volume element of the astronauts comes from internal stress. The normal force causes the astronauts to be compressed until the internal stresses are sufficient to accelerate the astronauts.

The only way to prevent the build up of internal stresses, is to accelerate the astronauts using forces that act more uniformly over their volumes. This can be done using strong magnetic fields, the human body consists mostly of water which is diamagnetic. You can float diamagnetic objects like [frogs shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1vyB-O5i6E) in magnetic fields of the order of a few Teslas.